# tfs31001 : cannot connect to tfs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I installed VS 2012 and connect to TFS but because of the framework 4.5 problems I had to uninstall framework 4.5 installed VS 2010 but now I cannot connect to TFS. 
I added the server, but gives error when I try to connect to project collection.
I uninstalled VS 2012. 
I cannot delete the local workspace and I think that might cause the problem. I get error:

TF31001: cannot connect to team Foundation Server at SERVERNAME. The server returned the following error: Field not found: 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.IntegrationServiceIdentifiers.SyncService.'

PS: My teammates can connect to the server.

How can I get over this issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you already tried to go to the TFS through a webbrowser by surfing to it from your machine? And did you installed [this piece of software](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082) to your visual studio 2010

Comment: I was able to connect to TFS through web browser. ınstalling the software didn't solve either. I formatted the PC and after format I didn't have any problems. Thanks anyway

Comment: Great to hear that it is solved. Hopefully it wasn't to much work to format the PC.

Answer (score 0):

This may appear like a strange answer but have you tried clearing your Temporary Internet files and cache? I've had a couple of problems over the years with TFS and have found this works for me generally with connectivity issues. Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ms244130(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I wish I tried that before format but didn't see your answer. Thanks anyway

Comment: So my answer was correct :) Except instead of clearing your temporary internet files you done a glorified version and formatted your machine and it worked? :)